# Second Activity show nothing in Android Studio

Tags: android

I am trying to create a second activity and adding a button inside it, but the design view of xml file show nothing.

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="85dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Design View show nothing like this

[image]

Comment: give background color to your button

Comment: there is no issue with this xml.

Comment: Added color but nothing shown. Is the activity needs to added in manifest file first in order to show?

Answer (score 0):

Just give the background to your Button.

```
<Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:background="#000000" // This is Black Color
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="85dp" />
```

Comment: Try this. If still issue is there, then please share your Code.
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/textViewEventImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="BUTTON"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>`